# configure cordova-plugin into capacitor environment

Tags: configuration, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I have a react-app webapp wrapped by an ionic-capacitor framework.
I already used a lot of cordova-plugins inside my code, like the phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner or the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.

I understood that i can use them if I make:
npm install --save cordova-plugin-pluginName @ionic-native/plugin-name

then i could import them into my React environment with:
import {PluginName} from @ionic-native/plugin-name

and it's works like a magic!

The problem is: 
when i need to use a cordova-plugin which requires configuration, it used to be cordova add plugin plugin-name --variable var=""

but in the react-capacitor environment i can't install the plugin with it's configuration! i should add it later somehow, via the androidManifest.xml or via the cordova:config.xml.

can someone help me please?
thanks a lot...

Comment: Each plugin can use variables in a different way, so you should check the plugin code and see what it's doing and try to do the same but manually. If you say which plugin you want to install I can try to give you a hand.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-that-require-install-variables-with-capacitor/

Answer (score 0):

Ionic provides a tool for changing the ios/android configs using a separate file. It's called [Trapeze](https://trapeze.dev). It does require a bit of extra configuration and an aditional build step but it will allow for the adding of these variables to the ios/android config.